# Stop debugging mode in brave browser every time i open it

Tags: debugging, browser, brave

Good day,
Every time I open the console in brave and the debugging mode is on, and my screen is over lay with stop pause debug thing.
Does anybody know how exactly to turn it off and get back to normal console ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you figured it out by now.
But, in case you didn't, here is a solution.

1. Open Developer Tools in Brave
2. Open Sources Tab
3. And make sure "Pause on Exceptions" is disabled.

Check the image

[image: 1]